# How can i set the variable rip in "info registers" in GDB console?

Tags: assembly, binary, gdb

How can i set RIP in "info registers" of a program with gdb? Like you do for eax, you type "set $eax=0", but how can i do for rip?

Comment: Yes, `set $pc = 0x123456`.  RIP isn't a "normal" register, so GDB treats it specially using the general "program counter" name regardless of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

`rip` is the instruction pointer, you'd use the `jump` instruction to set it and continue from the new address.